Meaning of the Ehrhart polynomial at $-1/2$?
I am studying a large collection of lattice polytopes, all of them being simple and empty. The dimension can be any integer. The dilatation by $2$ gives non-empty polytopes.
For many of these polytopes but not all, the Ehrhart polynomial $E_P(t)$ vanishes at $t=-1/2$, sometimes with multiplicity.

Q1: Is there a general meaning for the value of the Ehrhart polynomial $E_P(t)$ at $t=-1/2$ ?


Q2: What does the vanishing of $E_P(t)$ at $t=-1/2$ say about the polytope $P$ ?

ADDED: by empty, I mean no interior lattice point.

Feels vaguely similar to some observations of Postnikov and Stanley in their “Deformations of Coxeter Hyperplane Arrangements” paper where they show that the zeros of characteristic polynomials of certain arrangements lie on a vertical line in the complex plane with real part a half-integer (they call this the “Riemann hypothesis” for these arrangements).

By an empty polytope, you mean that there are no lattice points in its interior?

@efs more precisely, an "empty" lattice polytope usually means no lattice points other than its vertices (this is different than no interior lattice points because it also precludes non-vertex lattice points on the facets).

@efs the terminology for lattice polytope with no lattice points in its interior is usually "hollow."

@SamHopkins Thank you, I didn't know about that terminology.

A naive observation: for a polygon (ie, 2-dimensional polytope), Pick's theorem gives you that its area is 2, and that there are exactly 6 points in its boundary. A pretty "small" polygon.

Indeed, my only example in dimension 2 is the triangle with vertices (0,0), (2,0) and (0,2).
